# AS3: Loading external Google Maps XML file from AS3 without causing sandbox security error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to load an external XML file from the Google Maps API without getting a security sandbox error?

At the moment I'm using a proxy, but this isn't ideal as all API calls will then come from the proxy's IP and not the users.

Here's the test script:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://maps.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://maps.google.co.uk/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://maps.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml") 
Security.allowDomain("*.googleapis.com"); 
Security.allowDomain("*.google.co.uk"); 

var xmlString:String ='http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/geo?q=Slack Head LA7 7AX, United Kingdom&output=xml';

var myXML:XML;

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlString));
```

I've basically given up all hope and I've wasted hours. It seems odd that you can't load external XML/RSS feeds??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access XML files directly from Flash without causing a cross-domain scripting error.

However, Flash will let you access images and mp3's etc directly so you can call Google's static street view and maps APIs to get images, however, getting data is a different matter.

Some sites support JSONP which means you can use JavaScript (with jQuery library) to retrieve JSON/XML data and the pass that on to the Flash object.

Google Maps API doesn't support JSONP.

So, what you have to do is include the JavaScript Google Maps API 3 library in your HTML and then call JavaScript functions from your Flash (using ExternalInterface) which gets data from the Maps API and then you need to pass the retrieved data back to Flash.